# Is there a way of maintaining a lot objects in react state wiesly

Tags: reactjs

Hello my question is there a way to maintain a lot objects in react state without creating many variables. For example i have a catalog with products and i have (onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave) and some logic for taking different css styles for fade effect and others on a boolean condition with a variable that is kept in state.The problem is coming when i need 5.. 10.. 100.. products i need to have many variables for every object. If someone can tell what approach is appropriate to be taken. Thank you in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col, Row, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import CardBody from "reactstrap/es/CardBody";
import CardTitle from "reactstrap/es/CardTitle";
import CardImg from "react-bootstrap/CardImg";
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';
import { keyframes } from "styled-components";

import style from './Catalogue1.css';

class Catalogue extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {                   <-- here i need many state var's
            dropdownOpen: false,              
            visible: false,                          
            visible1: false,
            cardOn: false,
            cardOn1: false
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    enterMouse = e => {                            <-- need 4 functions 
                                                   for just two objects
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen,
            visible: true,
            cardOn: true

        }));
    }

    leaveMouse = e => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen,
            visible: false,
            cardOn: false
        }));
    }


    enterMouse1 = e => {                            
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen,
            visible1: true,
            cardOn1: true

        }));
    }

    leaveMouse1 = e => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen,
            visible1: false,
            cardOn1: false
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const { filteredItems } = this.state;        
        return (
            <Container className={style.container}>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <div className={style.div1}>         
                            <Card className={this.state.cardOn ? style.cardOn : style.cardOff}  style={{ width: '13rem'}}  onMouseEnter={this.enterMouse} onMouseLeave={this.leaveMouse}>
                                <CardImg variant="top" src="https://i.ibb.co/MDHYTJy/11482459963422.jpg" />
                                <CardBody className={style.cardText}>
                                    <CardTitle>Смартфон GSM XIAOMI MI 8 LITE</CardTitle>
                                    <div className={this.state.visible? style.fadeIn : style.fadeDefaultState} style={{ width: '13rem'}}>
                                        <p>
                                            * foo <br />
                                            * bar
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                            <Card className={this.state.cardOn1 ? style.cardOn1 : style.cardOff1}  style={{ width: '13rem'}}  onMouseEnter={this.enterMouse1} onMouseLeave={this.leaveMouse1}>
                                <CardImg variant="top" src="https://i.ibb.co/MDHYTJy/11482459963422.jpg" />
                                <CardBody className={style.cardText}>
                                    <CardTitle>Смартфон GSM XIAOMI MI 8 LITE</CardTitle>
                                    <div className={this.state.visible1? style.fadeIn : style.fadeDefaultState} style={{ width: '13rem'}}>
                                        <p>
                                            * foo <br />
                                            * bar
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>


            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default Catalogue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would make sense to hold an array value instead of defining individual keys for your objects. I see you're trying to do something with cards, so this should be especially relatable.

Consider the following code:

```
class Catalogue extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
       this.state = {              
          dropdownOpen: false,              
          cards: [{id: 1, name: "Jack", visible: false}, {id: 2, name: "Queen", visible: false}]
       }
    }

    toggleCard = (cardId) => {
       const cards = this.state.cards
       //flip card, update state
       const updatedCards = cards.map((card, index, array) => {
           if(card.id == cardId){
               return {
                  ...card,
                  visible: !array[index].visible 
               }
           } else {
               return {
                  ...card 
               }
           }
       })
       this.setState({
           cards: updatedCards
       })
    }
    render(){
       const cards = this.state.cards
       return(
           cards.map((card) => {
               return <div onClick={() => this.toggleCard(card.id)}>{card.name}</div> 
           })

       )
    }
}
```

So having something like this lets you keep your Cards all together in one component. It all just depends on how you setup your cards array, having an ID would make your life a whole lot easier. Then you need to plan how your event handlers update the desired cards by consuming those ids

Comment: Thank you this approach is looking nice it solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

You should move the state of cards inside `Card` component and use them without the state in `Catalogue`.

Comment: You mean to remove the state variables from the constructors state ? yes it works but if i have one function for every card it fires the event on all cards. Or i didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @BorisBorovski here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lxlj1vzyql)

Comment: You should completely isolate state to the `Card` component

Comment: i didn't see the other files in the fiddle my bad... btw the example is very good and its encapsulated perfectly i ended up using this one after go into many bugs with onmouse onleave : ) Thank you for the help.

Comment: @BorisBorovski glad to help you :)